# php - File location on server instead of $_FILES["file"]["name"] (POST)

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I have a function that upload to amazon s3 images that posted from some page.

```
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
    //&& ($_FILES["upload"]["size"] < 20000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    } else {

      //uploading here

        } else {
            echo 'Image not uploaded! :(';
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "Invalid file";
}
```

its working fine! but now i have an image on there server on `/tmp/` folder, and i need to upload this one, how can i do this?

thanks!

Comment: There is no code about Amazon S3 in your question. What did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) function

```
$uploads_dir = 'path/to/some/dir';
$tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
```

also, a good habit will be to put $_FILES["file"]["type"] into a variable, and use that variable in the if checks, rather than using the $_FILES array each time:

```
$_type = $_FILES["file"]["type"];
if ((($_type == "image/gif") || ($_type == "image/jpeg") || ($_type == "image/jpg") || ($_type == "image/pjpeg") || ($_type == "image/x-png") || ($_type == "image/png"))
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `move_uploaded_file` function. And `var_dump($_FILES['file']);` to see, what informations do you have about your uploaded file.

Your uploaded file is here, after uploading `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];`